# Installing WinDbg 32-bit on a 64-bit system

Tags: windbg

I've installed WinDBG on Windows 7 64-bit, however, I want to install the 32 bit version, not the 64 bit version. 
I found this link on the internet:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/cd004535-75f1-48ee-9176-574b344ddce1/how-to-install-windbg-32bit-on-64bit-system

Following the accepted answer, I do not have that path on my computer. 
I have:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Redist

However, there is no "Debugging Tools for Windows" folder in that direcotry like the answer says, only the VC folder. WinDBG is installed and working. 
What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Download Windows SDK and the installer is in the ISO image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download Windows SDK ISO file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) and install 32bit version from there. Also you could use `!wow64exts.sw` command to debug win32 process or dump using x64 version.

Comment: Do I have to extract the ISO?

Comment: You could mount it using any kind of virtual CD-drive software and run installer. Or extract it data with any archiver software, that supports ISO images.

Comment: This answer does not consider extension DLLs which cannot be loaded in wrong bitness. Also, IMHO x64 WinDbg will never create a 32 bit dump, so you'll always include the WOW64 layer, which is not what you want. Such a dump will not be useful, even if you load it into a 32 bit WinDbg later.

Comment: That depends on what do you want WinDbg to use for. If you want to simply view win32 memory dump, obtained for example afrer BSOD, you could use !wow64exts.sw and dont care about debugger bittness.